# XSLT 2.0 Header Leaks into Transformed XML

Tags: xml, xslt, transform, xslt-2.0

First, a thank you in advance.  Second, this is my first post so apologies for any errors or wrongdoings.

I am a noob w/ xml and xslt, and can't seem to figure this out.  When I transform some xml using xslt 2.0, some of the headers from the xslt leaks into the new xml.  It doesn't seem to do it in xslt 1.0 (granted the xslt is a little different).  Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<xml_content>
<feed_name>feed</feed_name>
<feed_info>
    <entry_1>
        <id>1</id>
        <pub_date>1320814800</pub_date>
    </entry_1>
</feed_info>
</xml_content>
```

Here is the xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/strict">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="xml_content">  
<Records>
    <xsl:for-each select="feed_info/entry_1">
        <Record>
            <ID><xsl:value-of select="id" /></ID>
            <PublicationDate><xsl:value-of select='xs:dateTime("1970-01-01T00:00:00") + xs:integer(pub_date) * xs:dayTimeDuration("PT1S")'/></PublicationDate>
        </Record>
    </xsl:for-each>
</Records>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the new xml.  Look specifically at the first "Records" element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Records xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/strict">
         <Record>
             <ID>1</ID>
             <PublicationDate>2011-11-09T05:00:00</PublicationDate>
         </Record>
</Records>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you put in literal result elements and the `xsl:stylesheet` defines a default namespace (with e.g. `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/strict"`) then that namespace applies to those result elements and the XSLT processor correctly emits that namespace declaration on the root of the result document. I am sure that happens with XSLT 1.0 and 2.0.

As for the `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"`, you can get rid of that by adding `exclude-result-prefixes="xs"` on the `xsl:stylesheet` element.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  The strict I did not have in my 1.0 xslt which would explain why I didn't have the issue there and the exclude statement worked as you described.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't leaking, it's doing what you asked it to do.

Every unprefixed tag in the XSL file is in the `http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/strict` namespace (that's what the `xmlns="..."` binding means). Don't forget, that an XSL file is at its heart an XML file, and is parsed like any other XML file.

But because your XSL template declares that those tags should be put in the output, your output tags will be in the same namespace too. Again, this shouldn't be surprising, as the fully qualified name of a tag is made up from the namespace and the local name.

So the XSLT processor has to bind that namespace to a prefix to produce the correct output and that's what you see here. (It was bound to the empty prefix, or the default namespace but it could in theory have been any other prefix, the output would mean exactly the same.)

The solution is simply to remove that namespace binding from your XSL or change it to whichever namespace you want your output to be in.

Comment: I knew it was a user error and it wasn't "leaking", but that was the best way for me to describe it.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the desired namespace for the element in your XSL by using xsl:element:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/strict">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="xml_content">
        <xsl:element name="Records" namespace="Something">
            <xsl:for-each select="feed_info/entry_1">
                <Record>
                    <ID><xsl:value-of select="id" /></ID>
                    <PublicationDate><xsl:value-of select='xs:dateTime("1970-01-01T00:00:00") + xs:integer(pub_date) * xs:dayTimeDuration("PT1S")'/></PublicationDate>
                </Record>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You'll get something like the following:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Records xmlns="Something">
   <Record xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/strict">
      <ID>1</ID>
      <PublicationDate>2011-11-09T05:00:00</PublicationDate>
   </Record>
</Records>
```

Do the same thing for "Record", "ID", and "PublicationDate" and you'll be sorted.